# Using Angular OpaqueToken to DI Config Object Doesn't Show Type Errors

Tags: angular

I'm using an OpaqueToken to inject a config object into the application that contains things like the API endpoint, etc.  I set this up using the Angular docs, and I was able to DI the config into a component and retrieve values.  I wanted to be able to type check the config so it exports an interface that is used by the component constructor during DI, but if I change the type in the component constructor from `AppConfig` to `string` no errors are displayed even though the type is wrong...

Anyone know why this doesn't show a type error?

**APP-CONFIG.TS**

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

export let APP_CONFIG = new OpaqueToken('app.config');

export interface AppConfig {
  apiEndpoint: string;
}

export const APP_DI_CONFIG: AppConfig = {
  apiEndpoint: 'http://example.dev/api/v1'
};
```

**AUTH.MODULE.TS**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// Config
import { APP_CONFIG, APP_DI_CONFIG } from '../app-config';

// Components
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ForgotComponent } from './forgot/forgot.component';
import { ResetComponent } from './reset/reset.component';

// Routing
import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // Angular modules
    CommonModule,
    AuthRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: APP_DI_CONFIG }
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    ForgotComponent,
    ResetComponent
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

**LOGIN.COMPONENT.TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

// Config
import { APP_CONFIG, AppConfig } from '../../app-config';

import { AuthService } from '../../core/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'cf-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  // Data model
  credentials: { username: string, password: string };

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    //@Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: AppConfig // Original
    @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: string // Should fail type check?
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.config);
  }

}
```

**Update**

@JB-nizet indicated InjectionTokens are used in v4, and though that still doesn't show a error in the type in VSCode it allows for generics on the token.

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<AppConfig>('app.config');

// TODO: get rid of warnings by splitting interface out into separate file
// NOTE: short term solution use a class instead of an interface
// export interface AppConfig {
export class AppConfig {
  apiEndpoint: string;
}

export const APP_DI_CONFIG: AppConfig = {
  apiEndpoint: 'http://example.dev/api/v1'
};
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have a compile-time error, but that said, in angular 4, OpaqueToken is deprecated in favor of InjectionToken<T>, which can at least infer the right type when getting the config from the injector.

Comment: thanks @JBNizet I updated app-config.ts to use an InjectionToken instead with generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't enforce type constraints at runtime, therefore when TypeScript is compiled to JS, this information is lost.

Static analysis doesn't get the information about providers and constructors connected. If you use `@Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: string` static analysis just assumes the passed value will be a string, and sticks with that information because of lack of more accurate information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I understand at runtime this won't throw and error, but shouldn't VSCode display the type error?  In the `InjectionToken` I've specified using generics it should be a specific type, and then reused that during DI of the config.  I thought this was the point of TypeScript, and I'm not sure what I don't understand.

Comment: There is no way of making a connection between `provides: [...]` and `@Inject()...` for language tools. That's only an Angular feature.